# Iterations in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, return-value

this is probably a very easy question for all of you.

I have a stochastic *Mathematica* code (not important what it's exactly) which gives me a number at the end. Now I want Mathematica to run this code 1000 times and put all the numbers into a list.

I tried by using the command `While`, but it gives for all of the thousand iterations the same number back.

How can I do this?

Edit: Perhaps it's better to show you the code:

```
XUJ = dataRe[χFF]["Values"] + I dataIm[χFF]["Values"];
XUJB = dataRe[χBB]["Values"] + I dataIm[χBB]["Values"];
PF[W_] = Δu/(2 Pi) (1 + 2 Re[uj.XUJ]);
PB[W_] = Δu/(2 Pi) (1 + 2 Re[uj.XUJB]);
dataLR = Transpose[{Table[W, {W, -((7 π)/10) + 2 Pi/10, (7 π)/10 - 2 Pi/10, Pi/10}], 
Log[Table[PF[W], {W, -((7 π)/10) + 2 Pi/10, (7 π)/10 - 2 Pi/10, 
    Pi/10}]/Reverse[Table[PB[
     W], {W, -((7 π)/10) + 2 Pi/10, (7 π)/10 - 2 Pi/10, 
     Pi/10}]]]}];

Last[LinearModelFit[Re[dataLR], x, x]["BestFit"]]/x
```

`dataRe` and `dataIm` generate the set of random numbers. 
Each time I evaluate now this cell I get a different number as it should be. 
I'm not sure how to implement this now into the `Table` command.

Comment: Probably you are storing the value to the same variable? Considering storing it an array. Use `ConstantArray` to pre-initialize the array for speed. It's difficult to say without MWE.

Comment: Consider `r := RandomReal[]; Table[r, {20}]`.

Comment: `results = Table[yourStochasticFunction[], {1000}]`

Comment: The question was put on hold because it contains a simple mistake? Could someone tell me where this simple mistake is?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and try;

```
f[x_] := (x + 1)/Sin[x]
myTable = Table[f[x], {x, 1000}];
ListPlot[myTable]
```

[image]